# NopCommerce - Category Images not displaying

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

I can't get category images to display in a NopCommerce theme. This is the code I'm using, on the `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml` page.

```
@if (Model.PictureModel != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.PictureModel.ImageUrl))
{
    <div class="category-picture">
        <img alt="@Model.PictureModel.AlternateText" src="@Model.PictureModel.ImageUrl" title="@Model.PictureModel.Title" />
    </div>
}
```

I've tried removing the if statement, and it just generates `<img>`.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i am aware, category images should be accessed like this..

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories)
            {
                count3++;
                <div class="sub-category-item col-4 alignCenter">
                    <h2 class="title">
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title" class="green">
                            @item.Name</a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="picture">
                        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = item.SeName })" title="@item.PictureModel.Title">
                            <img alt="@item.PictureModel.AlternateText" src="@item.PictureModel.ImageUrl"
                                    title="@item.PictureModel.Title" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 if (count3 %3 == 0)
                {
                     @Html.Raw("</div><div class='row'>")
                }
            }
```

this is a slightly modified version of the original nopcommerce code in a site i'm currently working on and this code works.
note that images are taken from the item.pictureModel rather than Model.PictureModel.

this is assuming that you have not moved this code into a separate file.

hope this helps

Comment: Can't get this to work, not sure why. It just doesn't display anything at all.

Comment: @Rev can you provide more information? have you debugged it? is the model populated with data at the point which you are trying to get the images out?

Answer (score 0):

Before using your code you should add the following code to the Category method in the CatalogController:

//prepare category picture model

```
        int picId = category.PictureId;
        int picSize = _mediaSettings.CategoryThumbPictureSize;
        var categoryPicCacheKey = string.Format(ModelCacheEventConsumer.CATEGORY_PICTURE_MODEL_KEY, model.Id, picSize, true, _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id, _webHelper.IsCurrentConnectionSecured(), _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
        model.PictureModel = _cacheManager.Get(categoryPicCacheKey, () =>
        {
            var pictureModel = new PictureModel()
            {
                FullSizeImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(picId),
                ImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(picId, picSize),
                Title = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Category.ImageLinkTitleFormat"), model.Name),
                AlternateText = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Category.ImageAlternateTextFormat"), model.Name)
            };
            return pictureModel;
        });`
```